# Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'datetime'

Tags: doctrine

> [Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'datetime' at position 52 in property Application\Entity\catalogTemplateVersion::$validUntil.

Here ist my Entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \DateTime @ORM\Column(name="valid_until, type="datetime")
 */
private $validUntil;
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the BUG. I have not closed the annotation(name).
... name="valid_until ...

Answer (score 0):

**Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'name' at position 27 in property**

Answer:
In this you have missed `" string` in your column

```
 /**
 *
 * @var \DateTime 
 * @ORM\Column(name="valid_until, type="datetime")
 */
private $validUntil;
```

to

```
   /**
 *
 * @var \DateTime 
 * @ORM\Column(name="valid_until", type="datetime")
 */
 private $validUntil;
```

**Note**
This issue always appear when you missed `""` or `,` in your annotation

I hope it will helpful

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * @var null|\DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="valid_until", type="datetime")
 */
private $validUntil;
```

Comment: Even though this answer looks like a valid one, you should provide some description of what the problem was and how it should be solved.

Comment: i commented already my solution => 

I found the BUG. I have not closed the annotation(name). ... name="valid_until ...


do you think it's not enough ?